# unicode string comparison in C

Tags: c, unix, unicode

I'm learning UNIX system programming.  I'm writing a simple shell application for UNIX (I'm on OS X Yosemite ver 10.10.5 and I use Xcode). I had some experience with C but not much.

Utility programs work fine and will print unicode characters (though ls prints '????' instead of it in Xcode console, but it seems to be the problem of the debugger itself).

I've made a little research and found out that `strcmp()` should work fine with it too, as far as it just compares bytes and looks for a zero byte in the end. Reading input should be ok too, as you just read bytes.

I've also read that unicode string shouldn't contain null bytes. However, some input will cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when doing `strcmp().

Code:

Reading user input:

```
char* readCommand(void) {
    int buffer_size = LINE_BUFFER_SIZE;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
    int position = 0;
    int character;

    if(!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "readCommand failed: memory allocation error");
        exit(ALLOCATION_ERROR);
    }

    while (1) {
        character = getchar();
        if(character == EOF || character == '\n')
        {
            buffer[position] = '\0';
            char* cmd = buffer;
            free(buffer);
            return cmd;
        }
        else {
            buffer[position] = character;
        }
        if(++position >= sizeof(buffer))
        {
            buffer_size += LINE_BUFFER_SIZE;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
            if(!buffer) {
                fprintf(stderr, "readCommand failed: memory reallocation error");
                free(buffer);
                exit(ALLOCATION_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Split args:

```
int split_string_quotes(char* source, char** argv, size_t arg_count)
{
    enum split_states state = DULL;
    char* p, *word_start = NULL;
    int character;
    int argc = 0;
    for(p = source; argc < arg_count && *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        character = (unsigned char) *p;
        switch (state) {
            case DULL:
                if(isspace(character))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if(character == '"')
                {
                    state = IN_STRING;
                    word_start = p+1;
                    continue;
                }
                state = IN_WORD;
                word_start = p;
                continue;

            case IN_WORD:
                if(isspace(character))
                {
                    state = DULL;
                    *p = 0;
                    argv[argc++] = word_start;
                }
                continue;

            case IN_STRING:
                if(character == '"')
                {
                    state = DULL;
                    *p = 0;
                    argv[argc++] = word_start;
                }
                continue;
        }
    }

    if(state != DULL && argc < arg_count)
    {
        argv[argc++] = word_start;
    }
    argv[argc] = NULL;
    return argc;
}
```

That's where strcmp is:

```
int shell_execute(char **args)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(args[0], commands[i]) == 0)
        {
            return (*standardFuncs[i])(args);
        }
    }
    shell_launch(args);
    return 0;
}
```

And the main loop

```
    char* current_dir = malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_MAX);
    char* args[MAX_ARGS];
    char* command;
    printf("dolphinShell (c) Alex Kale 2016\n");
    while (1)
    {
        getwd(current_dir);
        printf("dsh: %s-> ", current_dir);
        command = readCommand();
        printf("%s\n", command);
        split_string_quotes(command, args, MAX_ARGS);
        if(shell_execute(args) == -1) break;
    }
    free(current_dir);
    return 0;
```

So, the problem is that some unicode strings I type work fine and never cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but when I type `фывпфвыапы`, for example, it breaks. I think the problem is with accessing `args[0]`, but here's the debugger's output:

```
 Printing description of args:
    (char **) args = 0x00007fff5fbff900
    *args   char *  0x101800a00 0x0000000101800a00
    Printing description of *(*(args)):
    (char) **args = '\xd1'
```

So it thinks that `args[0]` is empty, but is it empty? Or is it confused by all the zeroes?

I'm really confused, I've spent a lot of time researching and seem to be stuck here.

I have also tried using `wchar_t` and `wcscmp()`, but it doesn't work good with `execvp()` and doesn't solve the problem.

I have also tried `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and here's the output:

```
main.c:53:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for(p = source; argc < arg_count && *p != '\0'; p++)
                    ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
main.c:92:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    if(state != DULL && argc < arg_count)
                        ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
main.c:124:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
        if(++position >= sizeof(buffer))
           ~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:180:18: warning: unused parameter 'args' [-Wunused-parameter]
int dHelp(char **args)
                 ^
main.c:203:18: warning: unused parameter 'args' [-Wunused-parameter]
int dExit(char **args)
                 ^
main.c:210:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
             ^
main.c:210:33: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
                                ^
7 warnings generated.
```

But I don't think that's the case (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: "*I've made a little research and found out that strcmp() should work fine with it too, as far as it just compares bytes and looks for a zero byte in the end. Reading input should be ok too, as you just read bytes.*" - that is only true if you are reading the input using `char`-based strings, either Ansi or UTF-8, for instance.  It will not work for Unicode strings that are read as UTF-16/32 instead.  You need `wchar_t` to handle those.

Comment: Also, your debugger output of `args[0]` does not show anything empty.  `args[0]` (ie `*args`) is the first `char*` string pointer in the array, which is not NULL in the output. `**args` (ie `args[0][0]`) is the first `char` in the first string in the array, and is not NULL, either. It is `0xD1`, which is the first **byte** of the Unicode `ф` character in UTF-8 (its second **byte** is `0x84`). All of the characters in `фывпфвыапы` use 2 bytes each in UTF-8 (thus `strlen("фывпфвыапы")` is 20 in UTF-8, not 10).

Comment: suggest you use `wcscmp()`  (found in wchar.h) as that function is made for comparing wide character strings.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression from the parameter to `malloc()`

Comment: the question states having a problem with wide characters, but the code is using the functions for 8 bit characters.  Suggest using the functions for wide characters.  Suggest declaring the wide character strings as `wchar` rather than `char`

Comment: these two lines: `char* cmd = buffer;
            free(buffer);` make a copy of the pointer that is contained in `buffer`, then passes the allocated memory back to the system, via a call to `free()`,  Then the pointer `cmd` points to nothing relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
        char* cmd = buffer;
        free(buffer);
        return cmd;
```

This returns a pointer to a deleted `char` buffer. Continuing use of this pointer results in undefined behavior.

```
        if(++position >= sizeof(buffer))
```

`buffer` is a `char *`. This is equivalent to:

```
        if(++position >= sizeof(char *))
```

Which would be either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your hardware platform. This needlessly resizes the buffer, every time it grows larger than 4 or 8 bytes.

You seem to believe that `sizeof()` gives the size of the `malloc`-ed buffer. It does not.

In conclusion: your overall approach here is to write a big pile of code, and then try to see if it works correctly. This is the wrong way to do it. You need to write one, small function. Such as the one that reads a line into a buffer. Test it. Verify that it works. Now that you know it works, move on and write the next small part of your overall program.

Comment: I get it. Thanks! However, it was working right until I gave it a unicode string. Guess I should pay more attention to what I'm doing. Big lesson for me.

Comment: Oh no, it could not. I added free(buffer) just before testing unicode.

Answer (score 0):

One huge bug in your code is the way you read the input. Look at this part:

```
if(character == EOF || character == '\n')
{
    buffer[position] = '\0';
    char* cmd = buffer;
    free(buffer);
    return cmd;
}
```

Here you are terminating `buffer` with nil, as you should. Then you assign `cmd` to point to the *same memory as `buffer`*, free the buffer and return the pointer to the *already freed memory*. If after this you use the returned pointer for anything it is not allowed and anything can happen. The memory could be reused somewhere, you'd get access violations or maybe a volcano erupts near you.

Assigning a pointer to another variable doesn't make a copy of the memory, it just makes them point at the same place. You cannot free the memory before you stop using the contents. This most likely is causing your issues.

Comment: Ooh I get it. That really should be it, don't know how I missed that one. I'll check later and see, but I'm sure that was the problem.